# Printing Question, then Question and Solutions at end of chapter in book class

Tags: exam, books, exsheets

My question is *almost* answered in other posts: I suspect exsheets is part of the answer. I am writing a book and have exam-style questions in the body with their solutions at the end of the chapter. I know exsheets can do this by use of the \printsolutions[section].

My specific issue: The questions (and their subparts) need to reprinted with their solution. Ideally, I would create a new command "\printquestionsANDsolutions[section]" to update \printsolutions[section]. There will be over 400 questions and answers (with subparts) in the book, so I don't want to re-write the questions as there is too much danger of drift during the revision process. I can rewrite things so that the questions are at the end of the chapter, but even then I don't want their solutions showing when the question is seen the first time.
There may be an alternative approach using delay [https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25501], but I couldn't figure out how to get the question/solution intermingle correctly.

The vision:

```
\documentclass[12pt] {book}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The First Chapter}
 
Chapter Text

\begin{question}
Question 1 text
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
Solution 1
\end{solution}

More chapter text goes here

\begin{question}
Question 2 set-up text
\begin{parts}
\part Question 2a text
\begin{solution}
Solution to (2a)
\end{solution}
\part Question 2b text
\begin{solution}
Solution to (2b)
\end{parts}
\end{question}

Chapter text goes on.

\printquestionsANDsolutions[Chapter]

\chapter{The Second Chapter}
Repeat of above.

\end{document}
```

The output would be

**The First Chapter**

Chapter Text

*Question 1 text*

More chapter text goes here

*Question 2 Set-Up text*

*Question 2a text*

*Question 2b text*

Chapter text goes on.

Solutions

*Question 1 text*

*Question 1 Answer*

*Question 2 Set-Up text*

*Question 2a text*

*Solution to 2a*

*Question 2b text*

*Solution to 2b*

**Chapter 2**

Repeat of above

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your code isn't compilable (as example, `parts` environment is undefined). Please correct.

Comment: Note that, for its author, the `exsheets` package is obsolete and has a successor called [xsim](https://ctan.org/pkg/xsim).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to handle the exercises in separate files and input them every times you need their content.

For example, move the exercises of the chapter 1 to the file `chapter1_exercises.tex` containing:

```tex
\begin{question}
  Question 1 text
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  Solution 1
\end{solution}
\begin{question}
  Question 2 text
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  Solution 2
\end{solution}
```

Input this file to display the question, with appropriate `exsheet` setup:

```tex
\chapter{The First Chapter}

Chapter Text


More chapter text goes here

\SetupExSheets[question]{print=true}
\SetupExSheets[solution]{print=false}
\input{chap1_exercises.tex}

Chapter text goes on.
```

Then, at end of the chapter input the file again, after setting `exsheet` to print solutions. Note that you must reset the `question` counter to get the correct numbering.

```tex
\SetupExSheets[question]{print=true}
\SetupExSheets[solution]{print=true}
\setcounter{question}{0}
\input{chap1_exercises.tex}
```

Full example below. The package `fancyvrb` is only used for demonstration, to generate the subfiles.

```tex
\documentclass[12pt] {book}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{VerbatimOut}{chap1_exercises.tex}
\begin{question}
  Question 1 text
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  Solution 1
\end{solution}
\begin{question}
  Question 2 text
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  Solution 2
\end{solution}
\end{VerbatimOut}

\begin{VerbatimOut}{chap2_exercises.tex}
\begin{question}
  Question 1 text
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  Solution 1
\end{solution}
\end{VerbatimOut}

\SetupExSheets{counter-within={chapter}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The First Chapter}

Chapter Text


More chapter text goes here

\SetupExSheets[question]{print=true}
\SetupExSheets[solution]{print=false}
\input{chap1_exercises.tex}

Chapter text goes on.

\SetupExSheets[question]{print=true}
\SetupExSheets[solution]{print=true}
\setcounter{question}{0}
\input{chap1_exercises.tex}

\chapter{The Second Chapter}

Chapter Text


More chapter text goes here

\SetupExSheets[question]{print=true}
\SetupExSheets[solution]{print=false}
\input{chap2_exercises.tex}

Chapter text goes on.

\SetupExSheets[question]{print=true}
\SetupExSheets[solution]{print=true}
\setcounter{question}{0}
\input{chap2_exercises.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image: solution with subfiles]

Comment: This is great! The one thing I cannot get working are questions with subparts - (2a), (2b) and so on. If that's not built in, is there a way to force the addition of (a) (b) in the title with a forced-counter reset?

Comment: @Squigglevoid That's another question. Subquestions are not provided by `exsheet` (by the way, `question` are called `exercise` with the `xsim` package). You have to create you own command, for example with a customize `enumerate` (see the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)  package). If the subquestion counter is reset for each exercise, you don't need to do it before reloading your files.